# How to force HtmlUnit to save page?

Tags: java, htmlunit

I'm using `HtmlUnit` to click on a `HtmlElement` that triggers Javascript action:

```
currentPage = ((HtmlElement) currentPage.getByXPath("//*[contains(@onclick, 'check();')]").get(0)).click();
```

The element is:

```
<a href="#" onclick="check(); return false;">
```

The page returned is quite similar to the page, containing that element: same URL, mostly same HTML, but there are some minor differences in the `HTML` and `HtmlUnit` doesn't save the new page. I'm using HttpAnalyzer to sniff the traffic and I see that the `Webclient` correctly handles JS and send the right request. The response is also correct, but when I dump the contents of the `currentPage` to a file, I see that the actual page didn't change. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
In my case it was:

```
<div id="loginButton" class="buttonOuter" onclick="this.childNodes[1].click();">
<div class="buttonInner">
<a href="#">Login</a>
</div>
<input class="loginHiddenButton" type="submit" onclick="submit_proc(false,'')">
</div>
```

I solve it this way:

```
HtmlPage page1 = webClient.getPage("myURI");
HtmlElement htmlElement = (HtmlElement) page1.getByXPath("loginHiddenButtonXPATH").get(0);

webClient.setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
page1 = htmlElement.click();
webClient.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```